# Adding properties to manifest file with spring boot

Tags: manifest, spring-boot

I want to add `SplashScreen-Image: <image name>` to the manifest file.

How do I do this with Spring Boot's Maven Plugin? If this is not possible, how do I create a single executable jar using maven with additional properties?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The answer was kinda obvious in hindsight. Spring-Boot's maven plugin rewrites the original manifest file so using the maven jar plugin the manifest can be written as normal. Like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <splashscreen-image>${image.name}</splashscreen-image>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: If you're using `<packaging>war</packaging>` make sure to use `maven-war-plugin` in place of `maven-jar-plugin`

Comment: maven-jar-plugin   works perfectly  if  <layout>ZIP</layout>  is used with spring-boot-maven-plugin.  +1

Comment: What code do you use to fetch that manifest property from within your spring-boot app?

Comment: Thanks. I was looking to do the same. Your solution worked for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for me with spring boot 1.5.22.RELEASE

Comment: @D.Naumovich it's the plugin version (`mvn dependency:resolve-plugins`) that matters here, I had the same impression as you with `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:2.7. 3` but in reality the plugin does not regenerate everything if the jar already exists, so you may re-test with `clean package` instead of `package` when changing `maven-jar-plugin` plugin configuration